# Show ProgressDialog and call OnBackPressed() after certain period

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xamarin.android, progressdialog

The *ProgressDialog* should display for 5 secs after which *OnBackPressed()* should execute. Currently the *ProgressDialog* never appears on screen. If I put OnBackPressed() inside the delegate progress dialog is displayed but then I get error that *OnBackPressed()* should be executed from MainThread. What can I do?

```
private async SomeAsyncMethod()
{
   await ShowProgressDialog();
   ......
}

private Task ShowMessage()
        {
            var progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Bestandskorrektur", "Bestandskorrektur wird ausgeführt! Bite warten...", true);
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                RunOnUiThread(() => progressDialog.Hide());
                OnBackPressed(); // Gives error.
            })).Start();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

UPDATE: Solution based on answers:

```
var pd = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Bestandskorrektur", "Bestandskorrektur wird ausgeführt! Bitte warten...", true);
                var h = new Handler();
                void action()
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() => pd.Hide());
                    OnBackPressed();
                }
                h.PostDelayed(action, 5000);
```

Comment: in onBackpressed() check progressDialog is still showing then dismiss it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a Handler().postDelayed() like below -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //hide progressbar
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

onBackPressed() should be called from the UI Thread. What Darshan has suggested is the correct answer. When you want to update UI from a background thread (in this case the thread that waits for your timer to finish) you should use Handler. In place of the thread, replace

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do your work here

                    }
                }, /*Delay in miliseconds*/ );
```

Comment: How do I use Runnable() in Monodroid?